# View the Log on device

Tags: java, android, logging

I want to view the `Log` on device i.e the `System.out.println()`.
I am able to view on *DDMS* but how to view on device screen while running an *APK* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have root on your phone you can use the `logcat` utility in the `Terminal` application:

```
# logcat
D/dalvikvm(  142): GC freed 200 objects / 8744 bytes in 254ms
etc..
```

It displays the same log (`/dev/log/main`) as the `adb logcat` command that was suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a Logcat app available for android.

**code.google.com/p/android-random/downloads/list**

Answer (score -1):

Run 'adb logcat' on the command line of your PC would also work. You want to see the log output on the device's screen though? Hmm, why? I don't believe you can call up a shell or access the logs from an application, unless your device is rooted.

What you can do, of course, is create a TextView in your app, and update its contents with whatever message you like.