# Where I can see the Log, If I have installed application on Phone?

Tags: java, android

Where I can see the Log, If I have installed application on Phone?
Example like

`Log.v(TAG, "Current State is - "+state);`

My application is crashing when incoming call comes. So how can I trace the Log or Error?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919798/view-the-log-on-device. U can get an idea.

Comment: where I can accept the adb path?

Comment: What may be the reason of crashing?

Answer (score 0):

You can install aLogcat app for Android to see application log.
Here it is: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result

Answer (score 0):

Get eclipse. Go to top UI bar and click Window -> Open perspective -> DDMS. Right there is everything you need. You'll be able to track allocations, view file structure, and it should open default with a LogCat window on the bottom that will give you an amazing amount of information for debugging! CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ADB installed (as I assume you do), you just connect your phone to your computer via USB, enable debugging mode, and type in:

```
adb -d logcat
```

from the command line on your computer. A lot of output will show up, and you can scroll through to find the output you are looking for.

You can also show only specific tags, such as `FOOBAR`:

```
adb -d logcat -s FOOBAR
```

By using this command, you can filter out only uncaught exceptions, which is useful for debugging:

```
adb -d logcat -s AndroidRuntime:E
```

You can read more about logcat [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).