# How can I get call on Emulator?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where I can see the Log, If I have installed application on Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502242/where-i-can-see-the-log-if-i-have-installed-application-on-phone)

My installed application on phone is getting crashed when any incoming call come or if we plugin/plugout charger. So I want to trace the error or Log.

Comment: `TitleDoesNotMatchQuestionError` in line 2 - seriously: do you want to read logs on the phone or do you want to receive calls on your emulator?

Comment: You've already asked this exact question - if you didn't get what you feel are good answers, consider rewording your existing questions instead of copy & pasting the same question into a new question. You will not get much help with your current behaviour

Comment: We cannot get any call on emulator. You have to use a physical device

Answer (score 1):

You can run the device in debug mode.
You can also simulate incoming call. From eclipse go to DDMS perspective. Now go to emulator control. Type a no and press call.

Comment: Is there any internet or wifi setting to be set?

Comment: No, for simulating a call on Emulator you need not to have any internet or wifi settings